# Prevent flexbox shrinking

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm using flexbox to layout a page because the *growing* behavior is useful. But I'd like to completely prevent the *shrinking* behavior.

Anyway to manage this?

Example code:

```
<div class="flex-vertical-container">
    <div class="flex-box">
         This one should grow but not shrink
    </div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.flex-vertical-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-box {
    flex: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 271, accepted):

Try setting the `flex-shrink` property to `0` on the `.flex-box`.

Comment: For some reason setting `flex-shrink: 0;` didn't work, but manually setting: `flex-shrink: 1 0 auto;` worked fine...

Comment: flex-shrink: 1 0 auto; doesn't seem to be a valid property.

Comment: they probably meant `flex: 1 0 auto;`

Comment: It appears that setting 0 to the flex-shrink property is not enough in this specific case.  When working with `flex-direction:column` you need to also set a `min-width` value to complete this objective.

Answer (score 56):

Add a `min-width` with whatever you want the smallest possible value of the box to be. Flexbox won't shrink the width below the min-width.

Comment: min-width does work fine, but in responsive design it doesn't adjust with the space if its less than the specified. flex-shrink is not working for me at all though.

Comment: Also, safari still uses min-width property for flexbox behavior, resulting in strange cross browser issues between IE - Safari and 'the rest'. Check the notes on can I use: http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox

Answer (score 8):

You can try to apply to the child:

```css
.flex-box{
    width: max-content;
}
```

Final result:

```css
.flex-vertical-container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.flex-vertical-container div{
  background: gray;
}
.flex-box{
  width: max-content;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-vertical-container">
    <div class="flex-box">
         This one should grow but not shrink
    </div>
    <div>This is shrinking</div>
    <div>This is shrinking</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unless you are targeting a very specific browser, `max-content` wouldn't be a good universal choice.

Comment: Not supported by IE and Edge. Supported by Chrome, Safari and Firefox. https://caniuse.com/#search=max-content

Answer (score 4):

There are two variants for prevent shrinking **flex-child**

set to **flex-child** this prop:

1. with explicitly prop `flex-shrink: 0;`
2. or with shorthand [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) prop `flex: 1 0; /* Two values syntax: flex-grow | flex-basis */`

In your case **flex-child** is `.flex-box`

Answer (score 2):

If like me your `flex-direction` is `row`, try setting the width of the child to 100%. That fixed the shrinking for me.

Answer (score 1):

There are already great answers here. The one that worked for me was `min-width` property on child element and `flex-wrap` to parent element.

Below is the working demo. You would notice the child with orange color is having fixed min width of 240px, it can expand, but won't go below 240px.

```css
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen,
    Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #e1eaf4;
}

.child {
  margin: 4px 8px;
  padding: 12px 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  outline: 4px solid #fff;
  background-color: #3794fe;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.child:nth-child(1) {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.child:nth-child(2) {
  flex-grow: 1;
  min-width: 240px;
  background-color: #e47f0b;
}

.child:nth-child(3) {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">
    <p>Child 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <p>Child 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <p>Child 3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Flex-shrink` didn't work for me.

I ended up using `white-space: nowrap;` on the children.

This won't work for all cases, but if the children of your flex parent are one-liners of text, it just might.

---

(if using TailwindCSS: `whitespace-nowrap`)

Answer (score 0):

`flex-wrap: wrap;` works
https://jsbin.com/zajojanamo/8/edit?html,css,output

```css
main {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: green;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 4px solid;
  padding: 16px;
  width: 50%;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>b</div>
  <div>c</div>
  <div>d</div>
</main>
```

Answer (score -1):

To solve that problem use `display: inline-flex` on flex container( the parent element) directly without changing anything in your code.